# Rotating an movieclip for a fixed amount od degrees smoothly

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm attempting to rotate a MovieClip by a fixed amount in degrees it has to me smooth etc so mc.rotate(int) is out.

Currently I have this which spins indefinitely:

```
    public function wheelSpinning () : void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startSpin);
    }

    public function startSpin(event:Event):void 
    {
        mc.rotation+=1;
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? First time doing it and I am stumped. Google fu returns a mixed bag of results, I fear I am putting using the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TweenMax library from [Greensock.com](http://greensock.com). It has a very helpful method/plugin: `shortRotation` which automatically rotate in the shortest direction (very helpful when the object is rotated over 180 degrees).

```
TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {shortRotation:{rotation:270}});
```

That's it.

I wouldn't use Flash's Tween classes - they are not very efficient.

Comment: +1 for the shortRotation method. Its a good timesaver in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
remove the event once you hit your desired rotation.

```
public function startSpin(event:Event):void 
{
    if(mc.rotation == someValue)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startSpin);
    }
    else
        mc.rotation+=1;
}
```

Solution 2:
Use flash's tweening! 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

Solution 3:
Use a third party tween library. I use Tweener http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a basic **[easing](http://gizma.com/easing/)** to keep things smooth:

```
private var degrees:Number = 2; // increase rotation by 2
private var easing:Number = .5; // easing value
private var finalDegree:Number = 90; // Degree the rotation will iterate to

...

public function wheelSpinning() : void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startSpin);
}

public function startSpin(evt:Event):void 
{
    var c:Number = mc.rotation + degrees * easing;

    if (c >= finalDegree) 
    {
       /* Prevent the rotation from being greater than the
          finalDegree value and remove the event listener */
        mc.rotation = finalDegree;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startSpin);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Apply the easing to the rotation */
        mc.rotation = c;
    }
}
```

Play with those values and find out the ones that fit your needs.
If you're learning AS3 I'd recommend you to avoid using libraries to animate and write everything by yourself. Although what is under the hood of the libraries is much more complex than what I presented here, you'll have a basic understanding of what is going on. 
Otherwise it's better to use a library that encapsulates all this funny Math and just worry about the logic of your application/game. You can find a lot of libraries out there, like **[GTween](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/08/gtween_a_new_tw.html)** or **[Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/)**.

Hope it helps.